# MVVM with Hilt,RxJava 3,Retrofit, Live Data and View Binding

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I currently get stock on this part. I want to display simple data from GSON and I practice using MVVM structure and with Hilt and "RxJava".

This is my "View Model" and I don't know what to do.(This is my first time using this structure and dependencies.)
At my "getTip()" function under my View Model how can i transfer the data from "tipsModel" to arraylist and if i did something wrong at my codes.

```
public class TipsViewModel extends ViewModel {


private static final String TAG = "TipsViewModel";

private Repository repository;
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TipsModel>> tipsList = new MutableLiveData<>();

@ViewModelInject
public TipsViewModel(Repository repository){
    this.repository = repository;
}


public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TipsModel>> getTipsList(){
    return tipsList;
}


public void getTips(){
    repository.getTips()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<TipsModel, ArrayList<TipsModel>>() {
                @Override
                public ArrayList<TipsModel> apply(TipsModel tipsModel) throws Throwable {
                    // What i have to put here to transfer the data from "tipsModel" to my ArrayList.
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> tipsList.setValue(result),
                error -> Log.e(TAG,"getTips: "+error.getMessage()));
}
```

}

This is my Repository

```
public class Repository {


private TipsApiService apiService;

@Inject
public Repository(TipsApiService apiService){
    this.apiService = apiService;
}


public Observable<TipsModel> getTips(){
    return apiService.getTips();
}
```

}

And this is my Model. it a simple model.

```
public class TipsModel {

private Integer id;
private String gameName;
private String gameMenu;
private String subtitle;
private String description;
private Object image;

public TipsModel(Integer id, String gameName, String gameMenu, String subtitle, String description, Object image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.gameName = gameName;
    this.gameMenu = gameMenu;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getGameName() {
    return gameName;
}

public String getGameMenu() {
    return gameMenu;
}

public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public Object getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setGameName(String gameName) {
    this.gameName = gameName;
}

public void setGameMenu(String gameMenu) {
    this.gameMenu = gameMenu;
}

public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setImage(Object image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

This is my Code on my fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = ActivityTipsViewBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@Nonnull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TipsViewModel.class);

    initRecyclerView();
    observeData();
    viewModel.getTips();
}


private void observeData(){
    viewModel.getTipsList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<TipsModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ArrayList<TipsModel> tipsModels) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"onChanged: "+ tipsModels.size());
                    tipsAdapter.updateList(tipsModels);
                }
            });
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    binding.tipsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((getContext())));
    tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(getContext(),tipsModels);
    binding.tipsRecyclerview.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but do you actually have a question?

Comment: my question is how to put all the result to the arraylist. at the "getTips" function at my View model. can you help me @HenryTwist

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to include that, I personally don't think it really says it at the moment.

Comment: Yeah i already did.. my bad bro

Comment: You need to observe your `tipsList` LiveData in the fragment or activity.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: i just wanna know. so i don't need put code inside of my "getTips()" function in View Model?

Comment: @GioDude please confirm your response result I think your response is a list instead of an object.

Comment: @RaoArsalan my result is also a ArrayList.

Comment: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

it gives me a error like this

Comment: @GioDude  just change your return type of getTips function to list instead of observable object in Repository class and remove your map method in ViewModel.

Comment: @GioDude  Great! can you please accept my answer if I post? it motivates me to keep contributing.